# getting scriptaculous autocompleter to behave like google instant

Tags: php, codeigniter, autocomplete, scriptaculous

You know when you start searching in an autocomplete search box, you get a list of possible results. From those results, say you click one of the items on the list, I want to take that item and perform another search to give another list of results. Just exaclty like how google works. if you dont understand me try typing into google search box something like 'ja'. It will give a list of possible results,when you select one of them, it does another search and gives another set of results.

Pls does anyone know how to do this with scriptalous autocomplete? or anyother way Any example on the net, will really really appreciate it.

I ma using codeigniter frame work (php) by the way

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do it. Personally I would do it in jQuery using the Autocomplete from jQuery UI.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

You could get it to load the results like it usually does but format them differently or extend the jquery ui. Would be fairly simple.

Since its possible in jQuery its definitely possible to do with the scriptaculous autocompleter but I am not familiar with it.

You would look at the place where the output is displayed:

```
<div id="autocomplete_choices" class="autocomplete"></div>
```

If you can style this the way you want it instead of it being like a dropdown then you will have your instant.

Comment: But it acts slow. I want a fast search like google instant. What you say?

Comment: You would have to do something custom that optimizes the data back from the website an also the speed of the javascript(ie turn off animation etc). I think google does fade in the results or similar.